# Pass data from a query to a view

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.3

The problem I have is that I do not know how I can use the data of a query in a view if someone can give me a serious idea, the form I use is this but it gives me an error:

My Controller:

```
public function edit($id){
    $datosProfesor = DB::table('profesor')->where('id', $id)->get();
    $institucionDB = DB::table('institucion')->get();
    $datos = array('datosProfesor' => $datosProfesor, 'institucionDB' => $institucionDB);
    return view('profesorView/editarProfesor', $datos);
}
```

My view:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <h4>Nombre</h4>
   <input type="text" name="nombre_profesor" id="nombre_profesor" class="form-control" placeholder= 'Nombre' value="{{$datosProfesor['id']}}">
</div>
```

The error that appears to me is this:

```
Undefined index: id (View: /var/www/html/Konecte/resources/views/profesorView/editarProfesor.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get()` method returns an `Illuminate\Support\Collection` containing the results where each result is an instance of the PHP `StdClass` object. You may access each column's value by accessing the column as a property of the object:

```
foreach ($datosProfesor as $profesor) {
    echo $profesor->id;
}
```

If you want to get a single result then you can use `find()` method as:

```
$datosProfesor = DB::table('profesor')->find($id);
```

which is a short form of:

```
$datosProfesor = DB::table('profesor')->where('id', $id)->first();
```

Just one more tip for you that you can use PHP's `compact()` method for creating array containing variables and their values. So that you can get rid of line

```
$datos = array('datosProfesor' => $datosProfesor, 'institucionDB' => $institucionDB);
```

Your final code will look as:

```
public function edit($id){
    $datosProfesor = DB::table('profesor')->find($id);
    $institucionDB = DB::table('institucion')->get();
    return view('profesorView/editarProfesor', compact('datosProfesor', 'institucionDB'));
}
```